# Switching on numlock by default in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, numlock

Whenever I boot in to Linux Mint the NumLock is switched off by default. As my username consists of some numbers, I need to switch on NumLock each time. I want it to be switched on by default each time I log in.

I had a look at the following question but could not find the `conf` file that the author is talking about:

[Enable num-lock as default in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23348/enable-num-lock-as-default-in-linux)

I dual boot with Windows XP and Linux Mint 14 Mate using the default US Keyboard Layout.

Comment: The .conf they are talking about in this thread is /etc/xorg.conf, the file responsible for the behaviour of the devices during your X11-session.
Do you mean log on your desktop when you 'log on'? If so, which one are you using out of the available Cinnamon, MATE, KDE, Gnome in the linux mitn distribution?

Comment: Tried numlockx?

Comment: No. What is `numlockx`

Answer (score 6):

in Linux Mint, this is easy:
1. open up 'keyboard' in settings
2. click on the 'Layouts' tab
3. click on 'Options...'
4. Under 'Miscellaneous compatibility options' there are many helpful options, including:

- Default numeric keypad keys
- Numeric keypad keys always enter digits (as in Mac OS)

Comment: I was so excited when I found the ability to lock numlock on was built in to linux mint.